# WorldPay Payment Response with http redirect

Tags: php, worldpay

The response URL is `worldpay-response.php`. When I do `print_r($_POST);`, I get the array which is returned from WorldPay. However, when I try to save the posted variables into session and redirect to confirmation page with

```
meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://localhost/confirmation.php"
```

`$_SESSION` variable do not have them. Do you know how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post how did you tried to save array in session.

Comment: Do the $_POST variables definately contain values?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing in which I can think is:

**make sure that you use session_start() in the very first line of your code.**

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It could be to do with the type of redirect you are doing.  Why not use PHP to do it?

```
header("Location: " . http://localhost/confirmation.php);
```